# How can I manipulate a named tuple produced via itertuples specifically to remove an element and produce a dictionary from the remaining elements?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, tuples, iteration

The question is best expanded upon with an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,4),columns=list('ABCD'))

def func(A,B,C):
    
    return A + B + C

for index,kwargs in df.iterrows():
    
    kwargs.pop('D')
    result = func(**kwargs)
```

The specific goal here is to replicate the above example, but deploy itertuples instead of iterrows, for efficiency.  However, when switching to itertuples, I am unsure as to how to manipulate the pandas.core.frame.Pandas objects i.e. pandas named tuples that are produced for each row in a similar fashion to achieve the same goal as the manipulation of the pandas.core.series.Series objects that the iterrows function produces.

Here is the idea:

```
for kwargs in df.itertuples():
    
    kwargs.pop('D')
    result = func(**kwargs)
```

Of course, neither line in the for loop works, because of the different objects that the new iterative method yields.  How can this be rewritten to achieve the same result, either directly (which I have not been able to find equivalent approaches for yet) or indirectly, without giving up the intended efficiency gains.

Thanks.

Comment: why not `df[['A', 'B', 'C']].sum(1)`? No sense trying to optimize an `.iter` method when vectorization will blow it out of the water.

Comment: This is a fair point and it is not clear from my question, but I need to pass the values as kwargs so that they can populate another object as attributes of that object.  The function was just used as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not convert the namedtuple to a dict?

```
wanted = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'D']
for row in df.loc[:, wanted].itertuples():
    result = func(**row._asdict())
```

You could also convert the dataframe to a list of dict

```
wanted = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'D']
for kwargs in df.loc[:, wanted].to_dict('records'):
    result = func(**kwargs)
```

Comment: This first solution looks like it also needs the argument index=False passed into the itertuples function.  In that case it seems to present the solution that I was looking for.  Thanks!